# What to do when an answer has been down-voted without a reason

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downvoting without given reason. What to do?!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21133/downvoting-without-given-reason-what-to-do)

I answered to a question reporting exactly when XML content is considered well-formed (see [Why does XML::Simple flatten this Tomboy note?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924588/why-does-xmlsimple-flatten-this-tomboy-note/1924848#1924848)).
What may I do if I think the down-voted was not deserved? I mean, the answer was correct, and was pertinent with what asked by the OP.

Comment: Maybe you were wrong?

Comment: Is it wrong saying that without a XML schema, XML content is considered valid if it is well-formed? If a XML file has a tag text, without a XML schema it is not possible to say if it can contain other tags, or it should contain only text.

Comment: Do nothing. Move on and answer another question.

Comment: You are burning through my close votes, you know that? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21133/downvoting-without-given-reason-what-to-do

Comment: If you want an answer reguarding a question about a specific question/answer it generally helps to post a link to it so we can see the context for your question.

Comment: I added the link. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *deal with it*.

If the answer is right, it'll be upvoted anyway, and that -1 will be a thing of the past. Unless you think there's tactical downvoting going on, there's nothing you can, or should, do.

:)

Comment: If there would be a tactital down-voting, I guess I should get proves of that. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, if you can't prove it, nothing will happen. The automated systems can detect most tactical downvoting, but still. Anyway, a single downvote on one answer almost certainly wasn't done maliciously :P

Comment: It would be rather difficult prove that somebody simply down-voted because he didn't like an answer, but still the answer was correct.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: exactly. If you think there's something you can do to improve your answer, then do it; otherwise, move on and don't worry about it.

Comment: @Shog9: I was just trying to understand how it works. It's not the case, but as I don't know all of 100%, I thought that could be a button on the page to signal cases as the ones I reported, or a specific page.